# AH01215: Malformed multipart POST: data truncated

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, perl

When loading the below script I get `AH01215: Malformed multipart POST: data truncated` error in Apache error log.

I need to pass files through AJAX, so I use `FormData` (in the below script for simplicity there are no file fields).

What is the error?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use CGI qw/:standard/;

if(param('ajax')) {
  print header('text/plain');
  print "YY";
  exit;
}

print header('text/html');
print q~
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  $.ajax({
    url: '', 
    type: 'POST',
    data: new FormData($('#form')[0]),
    processData: false,
    contentType: false // Using FormData, no need to process data.
  }).done(function(data){
    alert(data);
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<form id="#form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="hidden" name="ajax" value="1"/>
</form>

</body>
</html>
~;
```

Note that upgrading jQuery to a newer version seems NOT to solve the problem.

Comment: The code was with some minor changes copied from https://stackoverflow.com/a/25487973/856090

Comment: Put the `<script>` at the bottom of the `<body>` or use `$(document).ready()`. You're trying to read the form field before the form has been loaded into the DOM.

Comment: @Barmar Done, does not help

Comment: Use the Network tab of Developer Tools to see the parameters you're sending.

Comment: Form Data is `------WebKitFormBoundaryhpJVMdndG2j3wtaV--`. I do not know why it works this way (this is my question)

Comment: Do you see the `ajax=1` parameter in the Form Data?

Comment: `id="#form"` should be `id="form"`. The `#` is just part of the selector, not the ID itself.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for typo spotted. Now it works